# What is the (co)homology of a free (graded) Lie algebra?

Tags: homology-cohomology, graded-algebras, differential-graded-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology

In characteristic $0$, what is the Chevalley-Eilenberg (co)homology of a free (graded) Lie algebra?
Not the definition, but $H^i =$ ??

Comment: Which coefficients? Cartan and Eilenberg’s antisymmetrisation map $F^∗$ provides an explicit identification between the Chevalley-Eilenberg cohomology of a free Lie algebra $L$ and the Hochschild cohomology of its universal enveloping algebra $U(L)$.

Comment: In Weibel's book An Intro to Homological Algebra, he  H^*(L;M)=0 for* \geq 2 for L free Lie, but there is no mention of the graded case.Is it known?